# How to keep canvas listening events?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a snake game. Its gameboard is displayed in basic HTML code.

I have another game on the same page, but it is ran inside a canvas.

Would it be possible for me to keep listening key-events on both games simultaneously. For example when I click on my HTML code part to control the snake game, I would need the other game register my key-presses (arrows for example).

Let me know if there is a way to do that!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to listen event for both games, 
you can attach an event listener to its parent node

For example:

**In your html**

```
<div id="container-of-games" tabindex="1">
    <canvas id="game-snake"></canvas>
    <div id="game-board"></div>
</div>
```

Add a tabindex to your container so that it can be focused and receive key input.

**In your JavaScript**

```
function monitorKeyPress(event) {
    // Handle your keydown event here
    console.log(event.key);
}

var container = document.getElementById('container-of-games')
container.addEventListener('keydown', monitorKeyPress);
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/tr3edy0j/2/